# Why docx file is corrupted after creating with NPOI

Tags: c#, docx, npoi

**I wrote the simple code, but even it doesn't work.**
I receveid the file that MS Word can't open.

```
XWPFDocument doc;

using (Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(pathTemplate))
{
    doc = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}


using (FileStream fileStreamNew = System.IO.File.Create(fullPath))
{
    doc.Write(fileStreamNew);
    fileStreamNew.Close();
}
```

Comment: So did you compare the files? What's different?

Comment: You should provide more information, in order for others to be able to help.

Comment: Not being that familiar with this library, but knowing how big docx files can be, I'd be remarkably surprised if just calling the *constructor* caused an entire in-memory representation of the document to be created, so closing the stream it's working with before you're done actually using it is probably a problem. Can't help much with your real problem at the moment though since the whole piece of code can be replaced with `File.Copy(pathTemplate,fullPath);`.

Comment: Have you looked at the size of the file? Is it what you expect? Just out of curiosity, try calling `fileStreamNew.Flush()` before closing it to ensure that everything is written to the stream.

Comment: @ScottHannen - no need to `Flush`. Both the redundant `Close` (which calls `Dispose`) and the implicit `Dispose` call (from `using`) are specced to flush any final changes.

Comment: Thanks to all. That code works. It's my mistake. I used wrong typeConten when upload to client :
 return File(fullPath, "application/vnd.ms-excel", file);

Comment: Do you have picture with "wrap text" option on it?